# Magento sets a no-cache header so Varnish won't cache?

Tags: magento, varnish

I'm setting up Varnish on a magento setup.  However it seems that magento keeps sending a no cache parameter that prevents Varnish from caching.  How can I turn this off?

I'm using NGINX for my server so htaccess solutions won't work.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this issue is being thrown with both layout files that have the attribute `cacheable="false"` anywhere on the rendered page and also when layout factory create is called with the argument `['cacheable' => false]`;

Still trying to determine how to show those blocks in a "cached" way.. Maybe need to pigeon-hole those specific requests.

Answer (score -1):

look at this articule "Magento performance optimization with Varnish cache"

http://www.kalenyuk.com.ua/magento-performance-optimization-with-varnish-cache-47.html

Comment: This does not answer the question.